# RadRichTextBoxes - Performance and UI Issues

Tags: richtextbox, rad

**Problem 1**

In an effort to implement Spellchecking for all our textboxes, we replaced them with RadRichTextBoxes and Text Input Providers.
Even though the spell check functionality works great, it has slowed our pages down drastically (an increase of ~14-15 seconds).

When there are 3-4 RRTBs, it works fine, however if we put 100+ RRTBs (all with their own text providers -TxtDataProvider), it becomes a problem.

We just need to implement spell check, whether using simple TextBoxes or RRTBs. Please help figure out what changes we can do to the RRTBs to make them faster, or even suggest an alternative to this.

**Problem 2**

When using the Rad TxtDataProvider to fill the RTB, a bottom padding of 10-12px(between the text and the RTB bottom border) is introduced in the RTB which we're unable to get rid of by setting the MinHeight attribute. However, if we remove the TxtDataProvider, our MinHeight attribute starts working in the RTB.
Any ideas on how to make the extra whitespace go away?

Any advice/help would be great!

Pulkit